# Loading multiple json files with respective file name into dataframe

Tags: json, pandas

Reading the json files into the dataframe currently works this way but the file name is the same one for the two different files. Where have I gone wrong?

```
json_files = glob.glob(r"json_files\*.json")
df = pd.DataFrame()
for _,ele in enumerate(json_files,len(json_files)):
    df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_json(ele)])
    df['filename'] = os.path.basename(ele).strip(".json")
    df = df.drop(['pages'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, How about this code?

```
json_files = glob.glob(r"json_files\*.json")
dfs = []
for _,ele in enumerate(json_files,len(json_files)):
    #df = pd.concat([df, pd.read_json(ele)])
    df = pd.read_json(ele)
    df['filename'] = os.path.basename(ele).strip(".json")
    df = df.drop(['pages'], axis=1)
    dfs.append(df)
df_final = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: That would render one of the file names to NaN but in the wrong order. 
See this as an example: `df=pd.DataFrame({"filename":[2,np.nan],"json_key":["value from filename 1", "value from filename 2"]})`
but this is the expected outcome: `df=pd.DataFrame({"filename":[1,2],"json_key":["value from filename 1", "value from filename 2"]})`
Is there something wrong with the way I access the filename?

Comment: I have updated the answer so you can try it to see if it works.

Comment: This produces a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Sorry,  I have changed to dfs.append(df).

Comment: I have adjusted the code to 
```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["filename"] = [os.path.basename(x).strip(".json") for x in json_files]
df["text"] = [pd.read_json(x) for x in json_files]
```
While this displays the desired output, the json is displayed as text, instead of being loaded as json